# MissingMethodException on Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, instance, activator

I'm trying to create an instance of a foreign DLL. Unfortunately I get the error message "MissingMethodException". The command Activator.CreateInstance produces this error.
The creation:

```
Assembly lAssembly = 
    Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Siemens.Engineering.dll"));
Type lType = lAssembly.GetType("Siemens.Engineering.TiaPortal", true, true);

return (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(type: lType, 
            args: new object[] { 
                    Siemens.Engineering.TiaPortalMode.WithoutUserInterface 
                  });
```

the definition of the dll (abbreviated):

```
namespace Siemens.Engineering {
    //
    // Zusammenfassung:
    //     TIAPortal.
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public sealed class TiaPortal : IApplicationEntryPoint,
                                    IInternalApplicationAccess,
                                    IInternalObjectAccess,
                                    IInternalInstanceAccess,
                                    IInternalBaseAccess,
                                    IEngineeringRoot,
                                    IEngineeringObject,
                                    IEngineeringCompositionOrObject,
                                    IEngineeringInstance, 
                                    IEngineeringServiceProvider,
                                    IServiceProvider,
                                    IEquatable<object>,
                                    IDisposable 
    {
        //
        // Zusammenfassung:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the 
        // Siemens.Engineering.TiaPortal class.
        //
        // Parameter:
        //   tiaPortalMode:
        //     TIA-Portal will start in this mode.
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        public TiaPortal(TiaPortalMode tiaPortalMode = 
                          TiaPortalMode.WithoutUserInterface);
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this call. Since the constructor has an optional parameter, it should be able to be called with and without parameters. But both variants produce the same error. The assembly (lAssembly), as well as the type (lType), can be loaded correctly.
Any advice?

Comment: What is the *full* error you get?

Comment: Message: Der Konstruktor für den Typ "Siemens.Engineering.TiaPortal" wurde nicht gefunden.

Comment: ^^ "Cunstructor not found for type ..."

Comment: InnerExceptiion: null
StackTrace:   bei System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   bei System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   bei System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   bei test.TiaWrapperBase..ctor(OpennessVersionEnum aTiaVersion) in D:\Projekte\Rittmeyer\test\test\TiaWrapperBase.cs: Zeile45

Comment: Where is `Siemens.Engineering.TiaPortalMode.WithoutUserInterface` coming from? That type cannot be the same as the type the assembly loaded from `File.ReadAllBytes` is expecting (or rather, it could be defined the same, but it isn't going to match the type signature).

Comment: Example: TiaPortal MyPortal = new TiaPortal();
Or: TiaPortal MyPortal = new TiaPortal(Siemens.Engineering.TiaPortalMode.WithoutUserInterface);

The TiaPortalMode is an Enumeration:
namespace Siemens.Engineering {
    //
    // Zusammenfassung:
    //     Mode how to start the TIA-Portal.
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public enum TiaPortalMode {
        WithoutUserInterface = 0,
        WithUserInterface = 1
    }
}

Comment: Yes, but that `enum` needs to come from the assembly you loaded dynamically, you cannot define it separately. Try `lAssembly.GetType("Siemens.Engineering.TiaPortalMode").GetField("WithoutUserInterface").GetValue(null)` as the argument instead. And be aware that the type you are getting back here in turn cannot be mixed with other, statically defined code -- it isn't going to count as "the same" type. Depending on your scenario, you may be looking for custom `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` logic instead, rather than trying to be fully dynamic.

Comment: Either that or you already have access to the class type and it doesn't make sense to `Assembly.Load` it again.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: Does not make a difference. I also tried with a Zero.

Comment: Why can't you reference the dll directly and then just `var x = new TiaPortal();`?

Comment: @tymtam: 2 different version (V16 and V17) with the same namespace and filename.

Comment: What do you mean "2 different version"? Do you mean you'll have to support both in one wrapper?

Comment: Are there breaking changes between the two?

Comment: @DavvidG: I have now access to the dll. Later is no reference available.

Comment: @Fildor: Siemens.Engineering.dll (Namespace: Siemens.Engineering / Version: 16) and Siemens.Engineering.dll (Namespace: Siemens.Engineering / Version: 17). Different xml data and structures. I have to support both. (Later more)

Comment: _"Different xml data and structures."_ - In that case, I'd have a separate wrapper(-version) for each dll-version.

Comment: @Fildor: This is not an option.

Comment: Why? Supporting two incompatible dlls in one wrapper will be maintainance hell. You'll need a Facade anyway.

Comment: The user is working in a software called COMOS. In this software he starts my dll and my dll export some data to the foreign dll. Depending on the settings it use the V16 or V17. For me, it doesnt matter what the output is. (different xml data)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The addressed DLL is looking for a hard-coded path. If this does not exist, the same cannot be instantiated.